# Avoid oauth authentication for specific endpoints: Spring boot oAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am quite new to Spring boot OAuth. My application is using OAuth2 integrated with Azure AD. I want to have a URL which will not redirect to Azure AD for authentication. It was quite straight forward with Spring Security, we could configure something like this:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/someURL");
    }
```

Is there an alternative available for OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid specific end point authentication like below

```
  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/url/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes can allow access to everyone by using this

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatchers("/someURL").permitAll();
    }
```

for details [check.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html)